# Calculating mean value of polygons based on attributes of point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, calculate-values, mean

I am working with QGIS to compute the annual burned area of my study area in Chile. I have two different layers.

- One polygon layer which is a 1km x 1km grid of my study area. The only information this layer contains is a unique `"id"` for every grid cell.
- The second layer is a point layer of fires. It contains information about the size, direction and duration of the fire. Every point is one fire. Multiple points (fires) can lie within a grid cell.

I now want to compute the average size of fires in each grid cell. How can that be accomplished?

Comment: Step 1: Tell us which software you're working with.

Comment: @Erik I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example trying to mimic your situation. Please modify layernames and field names according to your project.

[image]

Above figure shows two layers: `Fire` point layer with size field, and `Grid` layer with id field only.

Start Field Calculator on the `Grid` layer, and give this expression:

```
array_mean(overlay_contains('Fire', expression:= "size"))
```

[image]

It will return averaged fire size. (It returns null where you do not have any fire).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I found another way which is way more time consuming. That saves me a lot of time. A hint for other people: array_mean is only avabile since QGis 3.18.